# Converting MySQL query to Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

How I can convert this MySQL query to a Laravel query?

```
select *
from marques
where id in (select marque_id from products
             where category_id = 'valeur1' or category_id in (select id from categories
                                                              where parent_id = 'Valeur1'))
```

Comment: Using the [query builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries). What have you tried so far?

Comment: Your current query is convoluted, and it would help to see some sample data.  There is probably an easier way of phrasing your query, and we should start there before hitting the Laravel code.

Comment: You should try first. If you fail then ask here. So show us your code here as proven that you already tried.

Comment: you can use query builder like- DB::select(
  SELECT *
  FROM marques
   WHERE id IN (
      SELECT 
       marque_id 
      FROM  
       products
               WHERE 
                category_id = :category_id 
                OR 
                category_id in (SELECT 
                     id 
                    FROM 
                     categories
                                    WHERE 
                                    parent_id = :parent_id
                                 )
                  ),
    ['category_id' => 'valeur1', 'parent_id' => 'Valeur1']
);

Answer (score 1):

I think your current query is equivalent to the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM marques m
LEFT JOIN products p
    ON m.id = p.marque_id
LEFT JOIN categories c
    ON p.category_id = c.id AND c.parent_id = 'Valeur1'
WHERE
    p.category_id = 'valeur1' OR
    c.id IS NOT NULL
```

Here is a rough guess at what your Laravel code might look like:

```
$res = DB::table('marques')
        ->join('products', 'marques.id', '=', 'products.marque_id')
        ->join("categories", function($join) {
            $join->on('products.category_id', '=', 'categories.id')
                 ->on('categories.parent_id', '=', 'Valeur1')
        })
        ->whereNotNull('categories.id')
        ->orWhere('products.category_id', '=', 'valeur1')
        ->select('*')
        ->get();
```

Comment: I think you made it correctly, thanks for your ans, I just guess you put `whereNotNull('categories.id')` extra to not get unwanted data

Comment: @C2486 This was the most painful question of the day...I hope it's right too, I can't test it though.